# Apollo refetch query when component mounts for a 2nd time with Query component?

Tags: react-apollo

I need to fetch a query when a component is mounted. The first time the component is mounted this happens automatically.

However if the component's page is navigated too, then the user navigates elsewhere, and then returns to the page, the by default the queries wont be refetched.

Using Apollo's HOC you can get around this by calling the `refetch` function on `componentDidMount`

```
class GetMessages extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.MESSAGES.loading) {
      this.props.MESSAGES.refetch();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, error, messages, me } = this.props.MESSAGES;

    if (loading) return <p>loading...</p>
    if (error) console.error(error);

    return <Messages messages={messages} />;
  }
}

export default graphql(MESSAGE_QUERY, { name: "MESSAGES" })(GetMessages);
```

However I know it's recommended to use the Query component instead. Can the same thing be achieved with the Query component?

Comment: You can probably solve it with a [fetch-policy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#supported-fetch-policies) of `cache-first` or `network-only`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `<Query>` component you would have to create a container class and wrap the present class with it and pass on the data as the prop of the child class. So an example would be something like this.

```
export default class MyPageScreenContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ApolloConsumer>
                {(client) => (
                    <Query query={GET_USER} fetchPolicy="network-only">
                        {({data, loading, error, refetch}) => {
                            if (loading) {
                                return <Text>Loading...</Text>
                            }

                            return (
                                <Mutation mutation={PUT_REQUEST}>
                                    {(putRequest) => {

                                        return (
                                            <MyPageScreen data={data.getUser} navigation={this.props.navigation}
                                                          refetchProfile={refetch}
                                                          putRequest={putRequest}
                                                          client={client}/>
                                        )
                                    }}
                                </Mutation>
                            )
                        }}
                    </Query>
                )}
            </ApolloConsumer>
        )
    }
}
```

Of course the problem with this approach is that it's pretty much the same as using graphql HOC. Also, when you refetch the data from the container, you would have to update the state in the child component with the same props to make sure re-render occurs.